# How to change the dimensions of an Eigen Matrix in a loop?

Tags: c++, matrix, memory-management, eigen, vector

I have a while loop, in which I use a Matrix `A`, vectors `B` and `x` with varying  dimensions:

```
int count=0;
while(true){
count+=1;

MatrixXd A(count,2*count);
VectorXd B(2*count);

// assignment of A, and B
//

VectorXd x = A.householderQr().solve(B);

// output of x

if (x.norm()>30)
break;

}
```

However the program built this way always collapses.
I tried to use pointers to such matrices or vector, and got similar failures.

How can I handle such issue?

Comment: You may need to deallocate the memory before changing the dimensions of the matrix.  What library are you using for your matrices/vectors?

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a size mismatch issue:  `A` is a `count x 2*count` matrix, and you are trying to solve `Ax=B` with `B` a `2*count x 1` vector.

Moreover, if you compile without `-DNDEBUG`, you should get a nice assertion telling you this is wrong.

To resize a matrix or vector:

```
A.resize(count, 2*count);
B.resize(count);
```